# How Can I Improve the Construction of this Embedding?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

**This is the construction**

We define $S^m\times S^n\rightarrow S^{m+n+1}$ by:

$f(x,y)=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y)$

where $x\in S^m$ and $y\in S^n$. This function is well-defined. Since the components of $f$ are polynomial functions, and polynomial functions are continuous, then $f$ is continuous. Also, $f$ is injective as $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$ gives $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$. That is $f$ maps distinct points in $S^m\times S^n$ to unique points in $S^{m+n+1}$.

Notice that $S^m$ and $S^n$ are compact. Therefore, their product, $S^m\times S^n$ is compact. Also, notice that $S^{m+n+1}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+m+2}$ is a submanifold. And since $\mathbb{R}^{n+m+2}$ is Hausdorff, then $S^{n+m+1}$ is Hausdorff. Therefore, $f$ is a continuous injective map between a compact space and a Hausdorff space. Hence, $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Lastly, for $p=(x,y)\in S^m\times S^n$ given by $D_pf$ has $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in its diagonal entries, and zeros elsewhere. This means the rows are linearly independent. Hence, the matrix has full rank (it has a rank of $n+m+2$). This matches the dimension of the target space $S^{n+m+1}$. Hence, $f$ is immersive at every point.

Since $f$ is a homeomorphism and an immersion, then we say it is an embedding.

Comment: "Therefore $f$ is a continuous injective map between a compact space and a Hausdorff space. Hence, $f$ is a homeomorphism" ...onto its image, i.e. a topological embedding, presumably.  Also $D_p f$ cannot _possibly_ have rank $n + m + 2$ since $T_p (S^m \times S^n)$ only has dimension $n + m$, and $T_q S^{m + n + 1}$ is only of dimension $m + n + 1$!

Comment: @BenSteffan What could I have done wrong here since the rank is obviously greater than the dimension of the target space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's much to improve about the construction itself apart from the issues pointed out in the comments. Personally, I would be a bit more concise since you spell out many rather basic facts that one could without problem assume known (such as that the spaces involved are compact Hausdorff). With that in mind, how about the following:

Let $f\colon S^n \times S^m \to S^{n + m + 1}$ be given by $f(x, y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x, y)$. This map is clearly well-defined and injective, hence a homeomorphism onto its image by the compact-Hausdorff lemma. Considering $f$ as a function $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\R^{n + 1} \times \R^{m + 1} = \R^{n + m + 2} \to \R^{n + m + 2}$, we have that $D f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mathrm{Id}$ and thus $f$ is an immersion and altogether a (smooth) embedding.

Comment: Is it necessary to distinguish between the $f$’s and call one the restriction of the other?

Comment: @MrProf I guess in this case it may not be strictly necessary since $f$ is just a scaling map. But I do suspect that the rank error in your post comes from just that: As a map $\mathbb{R}^{n + m + 2} \to \mathbb{R}^{n + m + 2}$, $f$ does have rank $n + m + 2$, but when you restrict to tangent spaces that rank goes down according to the dimension of the tangent space, i.e. to $n + m$.